# What are ある and わけ in 「どこにでもあるわけではありません」?

Tags: grammar, translation, verbs, conjugations

Here is the sentence for context.

> 独立系の映画館はシネコンと違っていて、チケットが安いのですが、どこにでも**あるわけ**ではありません。

My translation - Independent cinemas are different from multiplex ones as they have cheaper tickets but *not everywhere has one.*

Its the last bit of my translation that I'm not sure about, I can't seem to figure out what this あるわけ is. I know ある is 'to have' whilst ではありません is a negative state but what is this わけ?

Comment: If you're having problem with a particular word, stick it into the question title. Even if you don't know what it means, somebody else might and decide to post an answer. "What does this mean" doesn't have a lot of content, other than you want people to read your question...

Comment: Ok, I'll remember to be more specific in future questions, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your translation is close, but a little off.  The pattern `〜わけ{では・じゃ}ない` means "Does not (necessarily) mean that 〜".  The `ある` here is for existence, not for possession.  So it would translate as

> - 独立系の映画館はシネコンと違っていて、チケットが安いのですが、どこにでもあるわけではありません。　→　Independent theatres differ from big multiplexes; the tickets are cheap(er), but they are not (necessarily) found everywhere/all over.

I believe @Yakobu's translation is incorrect.  To make a claim that "there is no way they are everywhere" seems too strong.  `〜わけ{では・じゃ}ない` means the may not be everywhere, although they *could* be and the speaker just doesn't know it.  The point is that there is room for doubt.  Here are some examples I've found.

> - だからといってそれが間違っている訳ではない　→　"This doesn't mean (that) it is wrong"　→　It's inferred that it *could* be wrong.
> - と言ってもそれは君が間違っていないというわけではない　→　"However, that's not to say that you are right (not mistaken)"　→　It's inferred that you *could* be right (not mistaken).

Answer (score 0):

わけ here is from the kanji 訳 which you may have seen for example in 申し訳ありません.
It would literally be translated to "sense" I believe, but of course vary along this line with the context.

In your case, we have:

> ある訳ではありません

You are right for the ある and ではありません parts, if they would be seperate. In general, you can see ある訳 as to "have sense", so something like ある訳ないんでしょう？ would be "There is no way this/that is true/etc."

To answer your question, どこにでもあるわけではありません could be translated to "There is no way that they are everywhere" (hence there is no way you can find independent cinemas everywhere), and so to complete your translation:

> "Independent cinemas are different from multiplex ones as they have cheaper tickets, but there is no way they are everywhere".

Comment: I think that わけ here is usually written in kana.  I'm not sure about your "have sense" translation.  I think the literal translation of 訳{わけ} is closer to "reason" (理由) but I don't think it should be taken literally in this construction.

Comment: I think *sense* is a nice translation, but わけがない( no sense) is different from わけではない (not that sense)

Comment: Oh, I think I know where his confusion came from; he confused あるわけ*では*ない(partial negation) with あるわけがない(total negation).